# FormBuilder: Post-Submit Page not saved when changed

Tags: formbuilder, bug-reporting

I have created a submission form in FormBuilder, and initially referenced a holding page for the "post-submit page". However, when I have subsequently referenced a different post-submit page from FormBuilder, the updated post-submit page address remains visible on the configuration screen (even when the Formbuilder form is saved, closed and re-opened), but is ignored when a completed form is submitted (it uses the original holding page reference). I assume that this field in FormBuilder is not being read when the form is compiled at the point of saving it.

I can overcome the problem by cloning the form; when saved, the updated post-submit page works in the cloned version.

This would appear to be a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Just checking - you cleared the cache and force-reloaded the form in between?

Comment: I thought I had done so - but then I have tried it again and its working! How embarrassing but thank you!

Comment: I write from experience on this one!

Comment: This is frustrating. Having had some success, I now find the problem appearing again, across multiple devices and browsers, notwithstanding the clearing of cache and force reloading. I do think there is a problem here!

Comment: Try to replicate on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ ?